# I messed up and forced an install of a different glibc version and now I can't remove it

Tags: linux, centos, glibc

I stupidly forced an install of glibc 2.28 on my CentOS 7 machine that I need to get rid of but it complains that there are many dependencies.

I also have two versions of glibc 2.17 and only need one.

I have tried to dnf reinstall and dnf downgrade, but both complain.

Can I safely force uninstall 2.28 as long as I have 2.17 installed? Is there a better way for me to handle this? I am noob, please do not hesitate to ELI5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue, posting what I did for reference:

The issue was that I needed `glibc-2.28` for something but CentOS 7 only wanted to install up to `glibc-2.17`, so I had forced the `glibc-2.28` installation, which ultimately prevented me from compiling a program which required `glibc-headers` libraries.

- Attempting to `dnf remove glibc-2.28*` produced a huge list of dependencies.
- Attempting to `dnf downgrade glibc` also would not work, with the reason being that there was no `glibc-all-langpacks-2.28` counterpart for `glibc 2.17`.

I uninstalled this package with `rpm -e --nodeps glibc-all-langpacks-2.28*` and then was able to downgrade `glibc` without errors.